# How can I dynamically import a file in Compass?

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I have many websites which use the same layout, but uses different color themes. I would like a way to have the same scss for all the sites, but be able to choose a theme which can be imported. For example:

**site1/_theme.scss**

```
$bordercolor: #2200dd;
```

**site2/_theme.scss**

```
$bordercolor: #dd2200;
```

**style.scss**

```
@import "$site/_theme.scss";

.content{
  border: 1px solid $bordercolor;
}
```

Is there any way to get this to work, so it would import the correct theme partial based on a variable?

Comment: How is changing a variable value any different than changing the path to an import?